# SoapUI HTTP Monitor fails to record requests

Tags: proxy, httprequest, soapui, network-monitoring

I try to use `SoapUI 5.0.0` to record `HTTP` requests from browser.
I got this error when I try to access a non SSL secured site:

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /. Reason:
>
> INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
>
> Caused by:
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.AbstractMessageExchange.(AbstractMessageExchange.java:33)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.AbstractWsdlMessageExchange.(AbstractWsdlMessageExchange.java:36)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.monitor.WsdlMonitorMessageExchange.(WsdlMonitorMessageExchange.java:28)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.monitor.JProxyServletWsdlMonitorMessageExchange.(JProxyServletWsdlMonitorMessageExchange.java:86)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.monitor.jettyproxy.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:155)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.monitor.jettyproxy.JettyServer.handle(JettyServer.java:76)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

If a site uses `HTTPS` I see browser error message:

> Secure Connection Failed

I added `cacerts` file from `$SOAPUI_HOME/jre/lib/security` to `SSL settings`, but it doesn't work. I added flag `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` to `$SOAPUI_HOME/bin/soapui.bat` file too, but has same effect, couldn't server and record `HTTPS` requests.

Comment: Check with your service provider or with your team if developed internally.

Comment: @Rao : What to check please?

Comment: The same question.

Comment: @Rao : It isn't working in case of google.com, so it has to be some misconfiguration.